# CSS positioning content by active element

Tags: html, css

I want the active element to be centered in parent element when there is enough other child elements after and before it. When the active element is first of the children, it should remain on the left. When the active element is last of the children, it should remain on the right.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="recent-dates">
<a class="date-text" href="/14159#2020-08-05">Wed&nbsp;05</a>
<a class="date-text" href="/14159#2020-08-06">Thu&nbsp;06</a>
<a class="date-text" href="/14159#2020-08-07">Fri&nbsp;07</a>
<a class="date-text" href="/14159#2020-08-08">Sat&nbsp;08</a>
<a class="date-text" href="/14159#2020-08-09">Sun&nbsp;09</a>
<a class="date-text" href="/14159#2020-08-10">Mon&nbsp;10</a>
<a class="date-text" href="/14159#2020-08-11">Tue&nbsp;11</a>
<a class="date-text" href="/14159#2020-08-12">Tue&nbsp;12</a>
<a class="date-text" href="/14159#2020-08-13">Thu&nbsp;13</a>
<a class="date-text active" href="/14159#2020-08-14">Fri&nbsp;14</a>
<a class="date-text" href="/14159#2020-08-15">Sat&nbsp;15</a>
<a class="date-text" href="/14159#2020-08-16">Sun&nbsp;16</a>
</div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
   width: 500px  
}

.recent-dates {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #181717;
    height: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.date-text {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    padding: 10px;
}

.date-text.active {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #62E479;
}
```

Jsfiddle to illustrate the problem https://jsfiddle.net/koyz1arv/

I could do this by my self with JavaScript but may be there is some CSS-only solution?

**EDIT** (to make it clearer)

The active element should be be in the middle of the parent when there is enough elements before and after it. Spaces between child elements must stay the same.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: What do you mean with centered in the parent element? Should the active element be in the middle of the parent? Or do you want just something like Matt explained?

Comment: you said *you want to use CSS only*, so how CSS will insert class(active)

Comment: klediooo I updated the question. It is now clear enough?